# How to search by a property in array of objects in php?

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array something like given below
 is it possible to find the key index of the array if i provide a   slab id value in php?

```
Array
       (
           [0] => incentiveSlab Object
               (
                   [slabId] => 1
                   [templateId] => 1
                   [startPoint] => 0
                   [endPoint] => 1000000
                   [value] => 0
               )

           [1] => incentiveSlab Object
               (
                   [slabId] => 2
                   [templateId] => 1
                   [startPoint] => 1000000
                   [endPoint] => 2500000
                   [value] => 0.5
               )


       )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I will suggest, change your Data Structure

- use slabId as Array_Index
- Eg.

  Array

  (

  ```
     [0] => NULL

     [1] => incentiveSlab Object
         (
             [slabId] => 1
             [templateId] => 1
             [startPoint] => 0
             [endPoint] => 1000000
             [value] => 0
         )

     [2] => incentiveSlab Object
         (
             [slabId] => 2
             [templateId] => 1
             [startPoint] => 1000000
             [endPoint] => 2500000
             [value] => 0.5
         )
  ```

  )

> Or if you have too much variance in slabId use Associative Array

Answer (score 3):

Something like that :

```
function getIndex($array, $slabId) {
    foreach($array as $index => $item) {
        if($item->slabId == $slabId)
            return $index;
    }
}
```

Comment: i was looking for built in functions

Answer (score 0):

The solution should return the index if it is found like the above answers. However, it should returns something else if there is no match, like other standard functions such as [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) which returns `false` if there is no match. so `Max` answer may be modified, slightly, to be:

```
function getIndex($array, $slabId) {
    foreach($array as $index => $item) {
        if($item->slabId == $slabId)
            return $index;
    }
    return false; // or return -1
}
```